# Schengen travel insurance

Tags: schengen, insurance

I'm currently a resident of the UAE (Abu Dhabi) and need Schengen insurance for my euro trip but I am having difficulty finding a company which will give me insurance as I won't be returning to the UAE. I will be cancelling my residence and returning to my native country, South Africa.  Any advice on where I can get the insurance necessary for travel in the Schengen area even though I'm not returning to the country I am departing from?

Comment: Since you're heading back to SA after, did you try with insurers there?

Comment: You might find this post interesting : http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6397/from-whom-can-i-buy-travel-insurance-if-i-dont-live-anywhere I am wondering, what kind of insurance are you talking about? health insurance, flight cancellation insurance, to cover other objects, a vehicle?

Comment: @Vince “Schengen insurance” strongly suggests that it's about the mandatory health insurance needed to visit the Schengen area (with or without visa).

Comment: @Annoyed if you say so, I trust you (I mostly thought it was health insurance because most of the others are not really area-dependent)

Comment: So far neither SA nor UAE are wiling to provide cover as my departure and arrival country is not the same

Comment: @ Annoyed : A suitable insurance policy should provide adequate cover for medical expenses arising through illness or accident prior to or during the holiday and loss of holiday monies through cancellation or curtailment of the holiday or other insurable reasons"  The embassy also advises that the "minimum coverage should be  Euro 30 000 inclusive of repartriation flights"

Comment: @ vince: thanks for the link to that post! iv just viewed it and it seems to be exactly what i need!

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to buy insurance for a Schengen visa for relatives. In their country of residence the premium was ridiculous expensive and I searched for a cheaper opportunity outside their country of residence. I found an [online company](http://www.axa-schengen.com/) that issued Schengen Visa insurance, where I managed to buy the insurance.  They seem to cater the whole world.

I guess you need to state that your country is South Africa to be eligible for repatriation in case of an emergency to South africa, but you might want to contact them for details in your specific case.

Comment: @ Andra :I have tried the insurance company you have mentioned and because the country i am departing FROM is not the same as the country i will be arriving at after my tour, they are unable to provide cover!! really frustrated now

Comment: @ Andra: i will try adding my country off repartriation as South AFrica and see what happens! Although i am applying for the Visa here in the UAE.