# How to get travel insurance for a trip beginning in India and ending in the UK

Tags: international-travel, regulations, insurance

I am a UK citizen who has been working in India for the last year. When my contract ends I am going to travel from India to Nepal and then back to India over the next two months, before flying back to the UK where I will take permanent residence.

I want travel insurance (especially health insurance) for this trip, however all UK policies I have found require the trip to start and end in the UK and all Indian policies require you to be living in India, which I am currently but won't be from the point at which my trip starts.

Does anyone know of a travel insurance company that will cover me in this strange situation?

Comment: Related: [From whom can I buy travel insurance if I don't “live” anywhere?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6397/from-whom-can-i-buy-travel-insurance-if-i-dont-live-anywhere)

Comment: Thanks, I checked [World Nomads](http://www.worldnomads.com) and they will cover me as a UK Resident.

Answer (score 1):

I think key to the answer is "where I will take permanent residence." The moment you arrive in the UK you are technically still a resident of India. This will remain up until you take permanent residency in the UK. Just make sure your insurance applies up until that date, preferably some days after arriving in the UK just to be on the safe side.

If you need to deregister with the Indian authorities, simply ask to be deregistered on a future date. When I did this twice, this was possible.