# Travel insurance for elderly visitor from Georgia to UK

Tags: uk, insurance

I am preparing documents for a family member from Georgia to visit me in the UK for a period of about 1 month.  He is a citizen of Georgia and lives in Georgia.  I am a UK citizen residing in the UK.

I want to buy travel insurance for his trip, however, being in the UK, I can't seem to find almost any companies that sell travel insurance for people visiting the UK.  The only one I managed to find is http://www.imgeurope.co.uk - bit I'm sure there should be others.

Apparently, this family member tried to find travel insurance in Georgia but, according to him, it's not something that's normally practiced there.

EDIT: In addition, the person in question is over 66 years of age.

Any advise on how to approach this?  While covering missed flight connections, lost baggage, etc. would be a nice touch, I'm primarily interested in the medical cover.

Comment: I wonder if the answer to [From whom can I buy travel insurance if I don't “live” anywhere?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6397/from-whom-can-i-buy-travel-insurance-if-i-dont-live-anywhere) might cover you?

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks.  Unfortunately,  World Nomads Travel Insurance, mentioned in that question doesn't work, as they don't cover people over 66 years old - and my uncle is older than that.

Comment: FWIW, while he's in the UK he probably doesn't have to worry too much about medical cover... he'll be treated and the NHS will sort things out with Georgia directly: we have a reciprocal healthcare agreement covering most major things.

Comment: @JonStory Hm... I did know about this.  I'll research this a bit further.  Thanks.

Comment: That's not to say you should ignore travel insurance, just that maybe it's not as vital as if he were travelling elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what cities are involved or what airline, but most airlines while offer you travel insurance when you book the flights (since it's a useful option that also makes the airline money). So, I'd go through the flight booking process online and see if you get that option -- it normally turns up before you need to pay. Or check the website for the airline. Looking at airlines that fly from Georgia they all seem to offer some form of travel insurance.

Alternatively, most of their insurance is underwritten by AIG, and it appears you can apply directly to them. Here's the page with the [details](http://www.aig.com.hk/travel-direct-global-insurance_1930_388885.html) and from the [brochure](http://www.aig.com.hk/chartisint/internet/HK/en/files/Travel_Direct_Global_Insurance-pdf_tcm1930-625331.pdf) here are the key parts for you:

> Individual Plan: No age limit
>
> No nationality limitation except People’s Republic of China passport holder who travel to or within Mainland China

There's a footnote on the 'No age limit' part that says:

> For Insured Person aged below 17 or over 75, the Maximum Benefit payable under
> Section 2 (Personal Accident) is HK$300,000