# Is it possible to buy travel insurance when you are not starting or ending at home?

Tags: uk, insurance, denmark

I will be going to Denmark for 4 months. During this time I will be covered by insurance through work. In the middle of the 4 months I want to go on holiday to France for 2 weeks.  However, it seems that normal travel insurance only covers you if your trip starts and ends in your home country (in this case the UK).

Is it possible to buy personal travel insurance when you don't start or end the trip at home?

Comment: Which country are you from and buying your insurance from? I have done travel insurance from the USA that covered the scenario you ask without any problems.

Comment: @SheikPaul I am from the UK.  I was going to buy insurance from the UK but I don't actually mind where I get it from as it long as it covers me.

Comment: You should have no problems whatsoever. Does your work insurance terminate for the time you are off work? Did you check with your insurance carrier? USA insurance rules may be different from Europ/UK so I will defer answering to someone else from Europe.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, since this will depend on the terms and conditions of each insurance provider. My travel insurance 'kicks in' if I am more than 50km from my place of residence or place of work and not travelling because of work.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Standard UK travel insurance explicitly doesn't cover this case.  Maybe it's different in other countries?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6397/from-whom-can-i-buy-travel-insurance-if-i-dont-live-anywhere

Comment: How can a "Yes or no", "Is X possible" question be "too broad"... If there are lots of options, that's the answer to the question, not a reason to close it!

Comment: How would the insurance even prove you haven't been in the UK before your trip to France? EU citizens don't get stamps when traveling within the EU, nor are their movements tracked.

Comment: @JonathanReez They would presumably ask for documentation describing what had happened and the context as part of any claim. I don't want to enter fraudulent information.

Comment: You should also note that EHIC will cover you on France.

Comment: @JonathanReez Regardless of whether the insurer can prove it or not (and my insurer does demand evidence of the itinerary beginning in the UK whenever I make a claim), misleading the insurer would be fraud, which could have expensive consequences if later discovered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are some options *(these are based on browsing Columbus Direct purely because they're the last travel insurance company I used for travel from the UK, other suppliers are available/may be better etc)*:

- **Get a single-trip policy with Denmark as your "Country of Residence".** For example, http://international.columbusdirect.com/travel-insurance/single-trip-travel-insurance?countryOfResidence=DNK

  Unfortunately Columbus aren't a good bet for you here, since you'll only have been in Denmark for 2 months:

  > You must have been a resident of this country [your insurance's 'Country of Residence'] for at least 3 months.

  ...but other companies might have different restrictions.
- **Get a single-trip multi-destination policy covering the whole four-month period, Denmark and France,** with UK as your country of residency. This is probably the simplest option, but might not be the most cost effective. [From their FAQ](http://www.columbusdirect.com/travel/help/travel-insurance-faqs/#destinations):

  > **Am I still covered if I’m travelling to more than one country?**
  >
  > ***Single Trip policies:*** When you get a quote online, you will be asked to choose your destination from a drop down list on the first page of the quote. If you are travelling to more than one country, select 'Yes' to the question 'Are you going to more than one country?' above the destination box - this will allow you to choose from broader geographical regions, e.g. Europe or Worldwide.
- **Get a year-long multi-trip travel policy**, for all trips to Europe, starting before you go to Denmark, with the UK as your country of residence. These are usually quite good value for money and will cover any other trips in the year. [From the same FAQ](http://www.columbusdirect.com/travel/help/travel-insurance-faqs/#destinations):

  > **Am I still covered if I’m travelling to more than one country?**
  >
  > ...***Annual multi-trip policies:*** Please select the geographical region which encompasses all of your planned trips when obtaining a quote online. If at any point during the year you plan a trip which falls outside the regions stated on your policy - please contact us to ask about amending your policy.
- **Get a policy from an international provider with no country of residency restrictions.** This is a bit of a last resort option because this is a bit of a niche market and so it can be expensive. For more on this see [From whom can I buy travel insurance if I don't “live” anywhere?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6397/from-whom-can-i-buy-travel-insurance-if-i-dont-live-anywhere?noredirect=1&lq=1)

My personal recommendation would be the Europe year-long multi-trip option for simplicity and potential savings over the year if you travel again, and it also might help if travel-specific things aren't covered by your workplace insurance, for example, lost baggage when travelling between the UK and Denmark.

Alternatively you might prefer to shop around for narrower policies if you're on a very tight budget and won't travel again.

Comment: How do they define "country of residence"? Do I need to have been in Denmark for some time (6 months?) before travelling?

Comment: "at least 3 months", it's in the bit I quoted above (I took that quote from the popup under the `(?)` icon on their form)

Comment: Oops, I only just noticed you'd be going after only 2 months in Denmark! Maybe a different company has a different policy, will update the answer...

Comment: @eleanora Okay, answer updated

Comment: The multi-trip and multi-destination policies are not a way to evade residency requirements. If you are establishing a long term base in Denmark it is hard to argue that you are not resident there, particularly if you don't own property in the UK or cannot otherwise demonstrate some permanent connection to the UK. It is important to understand what the insurer regards as "residence" before buying these options. When making a claim you do not want the insurer to wriggle out of it on the basis that they regard that you were not resident in the UK during your trip.

Comment: 4 months in Denmark doesn't sound like a 'long term base' to me... but of course, check all the terms and conditions